# finding the subject of a verb followed by a comma in the end of a sentence

Tags: clauses

I saw him, looking very tired.

I saw him looking very tired.

What about these versions? what are the subjects of these sentences?

Comment: Isn't that comma unnecessary?

Comment: What form of pronoun is `I`? what form is `him`?

Answer (score 1):

`I` is *1st person singular subject personal pronoun* here, so only candidate to be called a Subject.